# How do I include a menu bar to show on top of my image slider? My slider seems to make my menu bar invisible

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slider').cycle({

            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            /* Change the fx 'fade' to 'scrollHorz' if you want*/

            speed: 'slow',

            timeout: 3000,

            next: '#next',

            prev: '#prev'

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            height: 250px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #container {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #slider {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 250px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="slider">
                <img src="images/bookline.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                <img src="images/fam.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                <img src="images/houseog.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                <img src="images/skyline.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Since there is no menu in the file you showed us, helping you will be quite hard. Please add the menu bar.

Comment: Where is your menu bar? Is it also `position: absolute`? If so, then you can add `z-index` css property to both elements, while making sure that your menu has higher `z-index` than slideshow. Basically put `z-index: 100;` on the menu and `z-index: 50;` on the slideshow and see where does that get you.

Comment: Sadly I am now facing another problem. I want to have the same thing done with my logo.. I want it positioned over the header but it too is doing the same thing. Actually when I add it within the content, it goes outside of the header completely